# Pass JS var to PHP var

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need to have a "global" variable because I need to use it in different page and I want to modify it too: I think that I need to use `$_SESSION`

I need to change this variable, when the user click on dropdown or list.

I have this:

**SOLUTION 1**

PageA:

```
$('#list.test li').on('click',function(){           
    choice=$(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
      url: "PageB.php",
      data: {word : choice},
      dataType: "html",
      success: function (data) {
      $('#content_table').html(data);                                 
      }
  });                                   
});
```

PageB

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['b']=$_GET['word'];
echo $_SESSION['b']; // It works
```

PageC for verify the result

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['b']; // Error !!
```

In my PageC, I have an error ( Notice: Undefined index: b )

Is it possible to update session variable with ajax ?

**SOLUTION 2**

PageA: I want to passe the id JS var to PHP var

```
$('#list.test li').on('click',function(){           
    choice=$(this).attr('id');
    <?php $_SESSION['b'] ?> = choice; //<--- it is possible ?
    $.ajax({
      url: "PageB.php",
      data: {word : choice},
      dataType: "html",
      success: function (data) {
      $('#content_table').html(data);                                 
      }
  });                                   
});
```

This solution doesn't work because AJAX and PHP are note in the same side (client/server).

Thank you

Comment: `$_SESSION['b']=$_GET['projet'];`: shouldn't that be `$_SESSION['b']=$_GET['word'];`?

Comment: oups, Yes it s" $_SESSION['b']", sorry, it's copy/past mistake

Comment: I think you need to wrap `word` in quotes in order for it to work

Comment: Any javascript errors?  does `choice` want `var` in front of it?  And no, it's too late to set the $_SESSION in the js.  You'll need to do it async like in Sol#1.

Comment: In sol1, I can send and echo the var "choice". I think, I need to send session variable with ajax !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Comment: I need to use the SESSION variable in every page so I can't use POST or GET method

Answer (score 1):

You can push data to cookies via JavaScript, smth like `document.cookie = "key=value";`

And receive it on back-end like `$_COOKIE["key"];`.

Comment: I don't want to use cookie ;) Is-it possible without it ?

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION['b']=$_GET['projet'];` should be `$_SESSION['b']=$_GET['word'];`

Comment: oups, Yes it s" $_SESSION['b']", sorry, it's copy/past mistake

Comment: trying print()ing that variable before assigning it. Try $_GET["word"] as well.